# How can we differentiate between zero and blank in a single expression?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I know there's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52049713/11774808), but its answers suggest using `ISBLANK`. That's fine for a cell reference, or even for a simple expression. But I have this:

```
INT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-ROW($BQ$3),BR$3,4,1,Selected_Element))<2)
```

I want to include only 0s and 1s, but not blanks. Using `ISBLANK` will require repeating this long expression.

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share some sample data with us to test the command to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
IFERROR(INT(CODE(...same indirect expression...)<50),0)
```

The `CODE` function returns these results for 0, 1, 2 and blank:

```
┌───┬─────────┐
│ 0 │ 48      │
│ 1 │ 49      │
│ 2 │ 50      │
│   │ #VALUE! │
└───┴─────────┘
```

So, I made use of it by wrapping it around the expression and ***changing the condition*** so that it checks for 50 instead of 2. Since it generates an error for blank values, we can wrap the expression inside `IFERROR`.

I tried other functions: `NUMBERVALUE`, `VALUE`, `TEXT(##, "0")`, but all these returned the same result for `0` and blank.

The entire formula looks like this:

```
IFERROR(INT(CODE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-ROW($BQ$3),BR$3,4,1,Selected_Element)))<50),0)
```